# How to write a custom Failure message for the Failed Step in Cucumber-java in extentReports

Tags: selenium, junit4, cucumber-java, selenium-extent-report, extent

I want to write custom failure message in my Cucumber ExtentReports.

Tool using :

> Cucumber
>
> Java
>
> Selenium
>
> JUnit
>
> ExtentReports

**What's happening now:**

I have a cucumber scenario.

```
Given something
When I do something
Then this step fails
```

The failed step Fails with:

```
Assert.assertTrue("CUSTOM_FAIL_MSG", some_condition);
```

In the ExtentReport, I see the
[image]

**What I want to achieve:**

[image]

**What I have researched so far:**

There is a `scenario.write("")` function but this creates a new info log into the report(But I am looking for CustomFailure message rather than a new log entry)

`scenario.stepResults` has the String which is displayed in the report. However, I could not find a way to set some value in the same.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: were you able to figure a way to do this?

Comment: Nope! not yet..

Comment: @SakshiSingla Incase your Question is still unanswered can consider updating the Cucumber jar versions `cucumber-core`,`cucumber-java`,`cucumber-junit` and `ExtentReports` version? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the create label markup?

Here is how to do it for the FAILED test:

```
test.log(Status.FAIL, MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName()+" Your MSG here!", ExtentColor.RED));
```

and the PASSED test:

```
test.log(Status.PASS, MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName()+" Test Case PASSED", ExtentColor.GREEN));
```

You can easily manipulate the string part (var interpolation?) according to your need.

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

try to replace the `JUnit` assertion library with the `testNG` library...also using `cucumber` you can see the failed step...why do you want to change this "narrative" log?...or if you want a better report try to use a 3rd party library